# How to set State after mapping over an array and object in react/JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, setstate

I’ve got a `patients array` in state. If the `patient.room` matches `roomStates.room` then I would like to set the `patient.roomStatus` to be `roomStates[key].name`. My function is as follows but I can’t see why its not working.

```
Patient array

const patients = [
{name: "Jay”, room: "room01", roomStatus: ""}, 
{name: "Leo”, room: "room02", roomStatus: ""}, 
{name: "Jim", room: "room05", roomStatus: ""}
]
```

```
const  roomState = { 
room01: {type: "info", room: "room01", name: "Stopped"},
room02: {type: "normal",room: "room02", name: "InRoom"},
room05: {type: "normal", room: "room05",name: "InRoom"},
}
```

```
   handleRoomStateChange(roomStates) {

        Object.keys(roomStates).map((key) => {
            this.state.patients.map(patient => {

                if (patient.room === roomStates[key].room) {


                    this.setState({ ...patient, roomStatus: roomStates[key].name});
                }

            })

        });
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide the actual code you're using. I'm not sure what the structure of `roomStates` is (you show a `roomState` variable but that doesn't seem to correspond). Also, your quotation marks in the `patients` definition are the wrong unicode characters - e.g. `“` instead of `"`. It would also be helpful if you described the behavior you're seeing instead of just saying "it's not working."

Answer (score 1):

Do not set state on every loop iteration, save the data into array and then set it once the loop is done executing:

```
handleRoomStateChange = roomStates => {
  const patients = Object.keys(roomStates).map(key => {
    return this.state.patients.map(patient => {
      if (patient.room === roomStates[key].room) {
        return {
          ...patient,
          roomStatus: roomStates[key].name
        };
      }
      return patient;
    });
  });

  this.setState({patients});
};
```

**Edit:** that actually returns a nested array, to get a proper data structure extra `map` can be avoided:

```
handleRoomStateChange = roomStates => {
  const patients = this.state.patients.map(patient => {
    const roomKey = Object.keys(roomStates).find(key => key === patient.room);
    return {
      ...patient,
      roomStatus: roomStates[roomKey].name
    }
  });
  this.setState({ patients });
}
```